# Make a vector of dosetime events depending on the number of input days

Tags: r, vector

I want to make a vector of dose time events depending on the number of days a drug was given. For example if a drug was administered once daily for 4 days then my vector for the times when the dose was given should look like this:

```
DAYS <- 4
dosetimes <- c(0,24,48,72)
```

I need help in how to make the vector update automatically, if I change the number of days.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `(seq_len(DAYS) - 1L) * 24L`? It's not very clear what you are trying to do. Not sure why you couldn't just multiply by 24?

Comment: I got an ansewer for myself: `dosetimes <- c(seq(0,(DAYS-1)*24,by=24))` Thanks David!

Comment: How is that better than what I proposed? You don't need to use `seq` or `c` here. Either Way, you probably should answer this yourself so this will exit the "unanswered" query.

Comment: Hi David: Yes. Both works similarly!

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer:

```
dosetimes <- c(seq(0,(DAYS-1)*24,by=24))
```

Another possible answer:

```
(seq_len(DAYS) - 1L) * 24L
```